# Qual evento devo associar ao select?

Tags: jquery

Meu script não tá funcionando, eu só quero fazer o script exibir o parágrafo quando o select for selecionado, vejam:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button id="btn1">Hide</button>
<select name="categoria" id="categoria">
   <option value="other">Other</option>
   <option value="show" id="show">Show</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa usar o evento `change` no `select`, e não no `option`.

Assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
        $('#categoria').val("other");
    });
    $("#categoria").on('change', function(){

        this.value === "show" && $("p").show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button id="btn1">Hide</button>
<select name="categoria" id="categoria">
   <option value="other">Other</option>
   <option value="show" id="show">Show</option>
</select>
```

O `change` não dispara quando o valor já está selecionado e você seleciona de novo. Por isso, no `#btn1` adicionei a opção que troca o valor do `select` quando o mesmo é clicado.

Comment: Por que que tem 3 sinais de igual ali? this.value === "show".

Comment: @DavidCesar não há necessidade nesse caso, mas os três sinais de igual significa que você está verificando o valor e se é do mesmo tipo. É que em PHP e Javascript, existe diferença entre `1 == '1'` e `1 === '1'`, ambos retornam coisas diferentes. Tem uma pergunta no site sobre isso.

Comment: Você pode me explicar essa linha:

this.value === "show" && $("p").show();

Vc usou operadores lógicos, não entendi.

Comment: @DavidCesar no Javascript, se o `this.value === "show"` for avaliado como `true`, ele passa para a próxima expressão depois de `&&`, que é o  `$("p").show()`

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o evento [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) do `<select>` e comparar se o valor selecionado (`this.value`) é o desejado. A partir disso você pode esconder ou mostrar seu `<p>`.

Exemplo:

```js
var $paragrafo = $('#paragrafo');

$('#categoria').on('change', function () {
    $paragrafo.prop('hidden', this.value !== 'show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="categoria">
    <option value="other">Other</option>
    <option value="show">Show</option>
</select>

<p id="paragrafo" hidden>Texto exemplo</p>
```